# How to define a function that is related to derivative of Jacobi theta function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I would like to make 3D plot of the following function.

```
F[x_]:=(x D[EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-Pi x)], {x, 2}] + 
      (3/2) D[EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-Pi x)], {x, 1}]) x^(5/4))
```

It did not work with F[1.0]. The error message is: 
     General::ivar: 1.` is not a valid variable.

So I define it as:

```
    G[y_]:=((x D[EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-Pi x)], {x, 2}] + 
      (3/2) D[EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-Pi x)], {x, 1}]) x^(5/4)))//.x->y
```

I can now do:

```
Plot[F[t], {t, 0, 3/2}]
Plot[F[I t], {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

Is there a proper way to define F[x] without using replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Evaluate.

Let's define

```
F[x_] := (x D[EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-Pi x)], {x, 2}] + (3/2) D[
      EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-Pi x)], {x, 1}]) x^(5/4)
```

First we plot the function on the real line

```
Plot[Evaluate[F[x]], {x, -2, 4}]
(* 141107_Plot _F (x).jpg *)
```

[image]

Now the 3D-plot for Re, Im, and Abs, respectively

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Re[F[z] /. z -> x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]
(* 141107_Plot3D _Re F (x).jpg *)
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Im[F[z] /. z -> x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]
(* 141107_Plot3D _Im F (x).jpg *)
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[F[z] /. z -> x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]
(* 141107_Plot3D _Abs F (x).jpg *)
```

[image]

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!  How about the following plot? Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[F[Exp[z]] /. z -> x + I y]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]

Comment: Hi, evaluating `F[1.0]` gives an error. The OP pointed that out and I think wants to avoid it.

Comment: @ Michael E2: you are right. Hence the best way to avoid it is to adopt Bob Hanlon's proposal.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Set` ( = ) rather than `SetDelayed` ( := ) so that the derivatives are carried out before x has a value.

```
F[x_] = (x D[EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-Pi x)], {x, 2}] + (3/2) D[
       EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-Pi x)], {x, 1}]) x^(5/4);

F[1.]
```

> 0.446697

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon: your idea is even better. I have compared the speed, funny but := with Evaluate[] is slightly faster than =.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Both methods worked for me.