# Imaginary terms in the derivative of Jacobi theta function (2) on the real line

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, special-functions

I am trying to calculate/plot the derivative of the second Jacobi theta function $d\theta_2(0, e^{-\pi t} )/dt$.

Calculating or plotting the function itself works fine:

```
In[1]:= theta2[t_] := EllipticTheta[2, 0, Exp[-1*Pi*t]];
        theta2[.8]

Out[2]= 1.07398
```

with the result being *real* - as expected [from Mathematica's definition](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta2/02/):

[image]

However, when I try to calculate derivatives of the above, I get a significant imaginary part:

```
In[3]:= dtheta2[t_] = D[EllipticTheta[2, 0, Exp[-1*Pi^2 *t]], t];
        dtheta2[.8]

Out[4]= -0.794774 + 0.280078 I
```

(Using `Set` (=) rather than `SetDelayed` (:=) as [discussed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65133/how-to-define-a-function-that-is-related-to-derivative-of-jacobi-theta-function). Taking the derivative of `theta2[t]` instead does not seem to make a difference).

Any ideas what might be going on?

(Note, the branch cut is [taken](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta2/04/05/01/) from 0 to -1, so should not be an issue.)

Answer (score 2):

One can use the [PDE satisfied by the Jacobi theta function](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta2/13/01/0002/) to compute the required derivative:

```
With[{t = 4/5}, 
     N[π^2/4 Derivative[0, 2, 0][EllipticTheta][2, 0, E^(-π^2 t)], 35]]
   -0.68549982086695914178518686511587505
```

(see the edit history for the older version of this answer)

Answer (score 0):

You are using insufficient precision:

```
theta2'[.8]

(* -0.794774 + 0.280078 I *)

Precision[.8]

(* MachinePrecision *)
```

Use exact arguments:

```
theta2'[8/10]
```

and get the exact result. Use `N` et. al. with desired precision to retrieve numeric values.

```
N[theta2'[8/10], 10]

(* -0.8874928427 + 4.596*10^-7 I *)
```

Comment: Thx for the reply, @rasher. I've tried increasing precision before and did not get any substantive improvements wrt size of the imaginary term (e.g., with above I get: `dtheta2[t_] = D[EllipticTheta[2, 0, Exp[-1*Pi *t]], t];
N[dtheta2[8/10], 10]
N[theta2'[8/10], 10]` output: `-0.3317952035 - 0.4122258903 I` `-0.3317952035 - 0.4122258903 I`) though the values in this case are different, which is also troubling...(using Mathematica 9).

Comment: @albert818: Hmm. Something fishy perhaps - I restarted kernel, got a different result (not matching mine in post, or yours). Then did exact calculation, *then* applied `N` to that, got a *different* result, but when re-doing the N[...] surrounding all version, it now matches the latter, though both are different from the post and yours. It appears to be caching results but something gets whacked  (try doing it with N[...,10], then re-do with say N[...,100], then re-do with N[...,10] again. Weird. Also on 9, btw.

Comment: Same story: did a complete program restart and got:  `-1.2947074204 - 0.4939796009 I` with `N[...,10]`, then ran `N[...,100]` and got `-1.0078730012 + 0.0790778685 I` (truncated paste). Back to `N[...,10]` - now same as `N[...,100]` (must be caching). Finally, did `N[...,1000]` and got yet another number and now same at `N[...,10]: -0.8874927502 - 2.184*10^-7 I`. This one has the `Im` part at close to chopping levels, at last(!) - but not sure I can believe it due to earlier instabilities.

Comment: Tried plotting with `N[...,500]` while setting `$MaxExtraPrecision = 500`, but still get the same pattern of significant oscillatory `Im` component (though the frequency of oscillations seems to have gone up, which suggests numerics to me). The whole thing is particularly odd, since I believe theta series are generally rather fast-converging due to the `n^2` term in the exponent... Any additional clues would be appreciated.

Comment: @albert818: I'm at a loss to further theories - hopefully one of the wolfram gang that hangs out here might have some insight, and perhaps pinging wolfram support might get some info.

Comment: `N[theta2'[.8`2000]] // Chop` returns `-0.887493` so "only" about 2000 digits of precision gives you what you want.